How can I create a new layout using Blazor Bootstrap?
I want to use Blazor Bootstrap's SideBar.
NewLayout.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="bb-page">
    <Sidebar2 Href="/"
              IconName="IconName.BootstrapFill"
              Title="Blazor Bootstrap"
              BadgeText="v2.1.0"
              DataProvider="Sidebar2DataProvider" />

    <main>
        <div class="bb-top-row px-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="py-2">
                @Body
            </div>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

<style>
    .bb-page {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    main {
        flex: 1;
        overflow: auto;
        min-width: 0;
    }
</style>

@code {

    IEnumerable<NavItem>? navItems;

    private async Task<Sidebar2DataProviderResult> Sidebar2DataProvider(Sidebar2DataProviderRequest request)
    {
        if (navItems is null)
            navItems = GetNavItems();

        return await Task.FromResult(request.ApplyTo(navItems));
    }

    private IEnumerable<NavItem> GetNavItems()
    {
        navItems = new List<NavItem>
        {
            new NavItem { Id = "1", Href = "/getting-started", IconName = IconName.HouseDoorFill, Text = "Getting Started"},

            new NavItem { Id = "2", IconName = IconName.LayoutSidebarInset, Text = "Content" },
            new NavItem { Id = "3", Href = "/icons", IconName = IconName.PersonSquare, Text = "Icons", ParentId="2"},

            new NavItem { Id = "4", IconName = IconName.ExclamationTriangleFill, Text = "Components" },
            new NavItem { Id = "5", Href = "/alerts", IconName = IconName.CheckCircleFill, Text = "Alerts", ParentId="4"},
            new NavItem { Id = "6", Href = "/breadcrumb", IconName = IconName.SegmentedNav, Text = "Breadcrumb", ParentId="4"},

            new NavItem { Id = "7", IconName = IconName.ListNested, Text = "Sidebar 2", ParentId="4"},
            new NavItem { Id = "701", Href = "/sidebar2", IconName = IconName.Dash, Text = "How to use", ParentId="7"},
            new NavItem { Id = "702", Href = "/sidebar2-examples", IconName = IconName.Dash, Text = "Examples", ParentId="7"},

            new NavItem { Id = "8", IconName = IconName.WindowPlus, Text = "Forms" },
            new NavItem { Id = "9", Href = "/autocomplete", IconName = IconName.InputCursorText, Text = "Auto Complete", ParentId="8"},
            new NavItem { Id = "10", Href = "/currency-input", IconName = IconName.CurrencyDollar, Text = "Currency Input", ParentId="8"},
            new NavItem { Id = "11", Href = "/number-input", IconName = IconName.InputCursor, Text = "Number Input", ParentId="8"},
            new NavItem { Id = "12", Href = "/switch", IconName = IconName.ToggleOn, Text = "Switch", ParentId="8"},
        };

        return navItems;
    }

}

I want to use it as a new Layout on my Client-side page. But it keep show me that 3 dot loading thing.(https://i.sstatic.net/Jp3jQFK2.png). There is a question about it link but App.razor in server project and it doesnt work for me.
I want to use it as a new Layout on my Client-side page. I found this video link2 as the closest thing to what I want to do, but it runs the pages on the server side.
In order to create "@layout NewLayout", the layout must be on the client-side, but even so, I cannot write @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly into the layout. gives the following error:

"InvalidOperationException: Cannot pass the parameter 'Body' to component 'NewLayout' with rendermode 'InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode'. This is because the parameter is of the delegate type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment', which is arbitrary code and cannot be serialized."


I did it and let me tell you how I did it, I created an empty layout on the client side and directed my page there with @layout. Then, I wrapped the sidebar in the HTML part of my page like a div. But now I have this problem: since the items do not have the OnClick feature and they only redirect the page with href, I cannot place a button that creates a modal in it. It has to navigate to another page and this is not what I want.

Based on your another question,you have to set InteractiveWebAssembly render-mode  gobally for your project
When you create a new project,select as below:

and follow the steps in the doc for interactive auto mode
but you have to keep the render mode  as InteractiveWebAssembly in app.razor
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorWasmGobal.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Add chart.js reference if chart components are used in your application. -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.0.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-gQhCDsnnnUfaRzD8k1L5llCCV6O9HN09zClIzzeJ8OJ9MpGmIlCxm+pdCkqTwqJ4JcjbojFr79rl2F1mzcoLMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <!-- Add chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js reference if chart components with data label feature is used in your application. -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <!-- Add sortable.js reference if SortableList component is used in your application. -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

The reason that I suggest you select interactive location as gobal is that the nav items would only be load during  OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle event .
If you set Interactive location as per component,the  layout would be rendered as static and  OnAfterRenderAsync event won't be triggered,and the side bar will keep loading
public class Sidebar : BlazorBootstrapComponentBase
{
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private bool collapseSidebar;

    private bool isMobile;

    private IEnumerable<NavItem>? items;

    private DotNetObjectReference<Sidebar> objRef;

    private bool requestInProgress;

    protected override string? ClassNames => BlazorBootstrapComponentBase.BuildClassNames(base.Class, ("bb-sidebar", true), ("collapsed", collapseSidebar), ("expanded", !collapseSidebar));

    protected override string? StyleNames => BlazorBootstrapComponentBase.BuildStyleNames(base.Style, ("--bb-sidebar-width: " + Width.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + WidthUnit.ToCssString() + ";", Width > 0f));

    [Parameter]
    public string? BadgeText { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? CustomIconName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public SidebarDataProviderDelegate? DataProvider { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Href { get; set; } = string.Empty;


    [Parameter]
    public IconName IconName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? ImageSrc { get; set; }

    private string? navMenuCssClass => GetNavMenuCssClass();

    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public string? Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public float Width { get; set; } = 270f;


    [Parameter]
    public Unit WidthUnit { get; set; } = Unit.Px;


    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await base.JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.blazorBootstrap.sidebar.initialize", base.Id, objRef);
            bsWindowResize(await JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeAsync<int>(base.JSRuntime, "window.blazorBootstrap.sidebar.windowSize", Array.Empty<object>()));
            await RefreshDataAsync(firstRender);
        }

        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (objRef == null)
        {
            objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        }

        if (base.AdditionalAttributes == null)
        {
            base.AdditionalAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void bsWindowResize(int width)
    {
        if (width < 641)
        {
            isMobile = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isMobile = false;
        }
    }

    public async Task RefreshDataAsync(bool firstRender = false)
    {
        if (requestInProgress)
        {
            return;
        }

        requestInProgress = true;
        if (DataProvider != null)
        {
            SidebarDataProviderRequest request = new SidebarDataProviderRequest();
            SidebarDataProviderResult sidebarDataProviderResult = await DataProvider(request);
            Sidebar sidebar = this;
            IEnumerable<NavItem>? enumerable2;
            if (sidebarDataProviderResult == null)
            {
                IEnumerable<NavItem> enumerable = new List<NavItem>();
                enumerable2 = enumerable;
            }
            else
            {
                enumerable2 = sidebarDataProviderResult.Data;
            }

            sidebar.items = enumerable2;
        }

        requestInProgress = false;
        await InvokeAsync((Action)base.StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void ToggleSidebar()
    {
        collapseSidebar = !collapseSidebar;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    internal void HideNavMenuOnMobile()
    {
        if (isMobile && !collapseNavMenu)
        {
            collapseNavMenu = true;
        }
    }

    private string GetNavMenuCssClass()
    {
        HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
        if (collapseNavMenu)
        {
            hashSet.Add("collapse");
        }

        hashSet.Add("bb-sidebar-content nav-scrollable bb-scrollbar");
        if (collapseSidebar)
        {
            hashSet.Add("bb-scrollbar-hidden");
        }

        return string.Join(" ", hashSet);
    }

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
        TypeInference.CreateCascadingValue_0(__builder, 0, 1, __arg0: true, 2, this, 3, delegate (RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)
        {
            TypeInference.CreateCascadingValue_1(__builder2, 4, 5, collapseSidebar, 6, delegate (RenderTreeBuilder __builder3)
            {
                __builder3.OpenElement(7, "aside");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(8, "id", base.Id);
                __builder3.AddAttribute(9, "class", ClassNames);
                __builder3.AddAttribute(10, "style", StyleNames);
                __builder3.AddAttribute(11, "role", "navigation");
                __builder3.AddMultipleAttributes(12, RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)base.AdditionalAttributes));
                __builder3.AddAttribute(13, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                __builder3.AddElementReferenceCapture(14, delegate (ElementReference __value)
                {
                    base.Element = __value;
                });
                __builder3.OpenElement(15, "div");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(16, "class", "bb-sidebar-top-row navbar");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(17, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                __builder3.OpenElement(18, "div");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(19, "class", "container-fluid ps-3");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(20, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                __builder3.OpenElement(21, "a");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(22, "class", "navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(23, "href", Href);
                __builder3.AddAttribute(24, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ImageSrc))
                {
                    __builder3.OpenElement(25, "span");
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(26, "class", "navbar-brand-image me-2");
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(27, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                    __builder3.OpenElement(28, "img");
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(29, "src", ImageSrc);
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(30, "alt", Title);
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(31, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                    __builder3.CloseElement();
                    __builder3.CloseElement();
                }
                else
                {
                    __builder3.OpenElement(32, "span");
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(33, "class", "navbar-brand-icon");
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(34, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                    __builder3.OpenComponent<Icon>(35);
                    __builder3.AddComponentParameter(36, "Name", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck(IconName));
                    __builder3.AddComponentParameter(37, "CustomIconName", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck(CustomIconName));
                    __builder3.AddComponentParameter(38, "Class", "fs-4 me-2");
                    __builder3.CloseComponent();
                    __builder3.CloseElement();
                }

                __builder3.OpenElement(39, "span");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(40, "class", "navbar-brand-text fw-semibold expanded-only me-2");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(41, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                __builder3.AddContent(42, Title);
                __builder3.CloseElement();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BadgeText))
                {
                    __builder3.OpenElement(43, "span");
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(44, "class", "navbar-brand-badge badge expanded-only");
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(45, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                    __builder3.AddContent(46, BadgeText);
                    __builder3.CloseElement();
                }

                __builder3.CloseElement();
                __builder3.AddMarkupContent(47, "\r\n                    ");
                __builder3.OpenElement(48, "button");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(49, "title", "Navigation menu");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(50, "class", "navbar-toggler px-2");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(51, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>((object)this, (Action)ToggleNavMenu));
                __builder3.AddAttribute(52, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                __builder3.AddMarkupContent(53, "<span class=\"navbar-toggler-icon bi bi-list\" b-h9l5f7lx3r></span>");
                __builder3.CloseElement();
                __builder3.CloseElement();
                __builder3.CloseElement();
                __builder3.AddMarkupContent(54, "\r\n\r\n            ");
                __builder3.OpenElement(55, "div");
                __builder3.AddAttribute(56, "class", navMenuCssClass);
                __builder3.AddAttribute(57, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                if (items == null)
                {
                    __builder3.OpenElement(58, "div");
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(59, "class", "text-center my-2");
                    __builder3.AddAttribute(60, "b-h9l5f7lx3r");
                    __builder3.OpenComponent<Spinner>(61);
                    __builder3.AddComponentParameter(62, "Type", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck(SpinnerType.Dots));
                    __builder3.AddComponentParameter(63, "Color", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck(SpinnerColor.Secondary));
                    __builder3.CloseComponent();
                    __builder3.CloseElement();
                }
                else
                {
                    __builder3.OpenComponent<SidebarItemGroup>(64);
                    __builder3.AddComponentParameter(65, "NavItems", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck(items));
                    __builder3.CloseComponent();
                }

                __builder3.CloseElement();
                __builder3.CloseElement();
            });
        });
    }
}

